# How to add Uri in VideoView in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am making simple videoview app from this link 
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example

Now what should be the Uri here, i mean should i write path like: 
"C:\Folder 1\file.mp4"

I am usin mp4 file from :
http://www.mp4mobi.com/mp41315287045/Swept_Away_Bride.htm

Answer (score 2):

see this example code

```
package com.video.tab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this){
        /*public void hide()
        {
            mc.show();
        }*/
    });
   //videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.androidbook.com/akc/filestorage/android/documentfiles/3389/movie.mp4"));
 videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/rabbit-and-snail.3gp");
   videoView.requestFocus();
   videoView.start();


}

}
```

in this ,uri locates the path of the ur video file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the video file to your sdcard.
Use:
Uri.parse("file:/sdcard/videofilename")

Should work.

Comment: adb push (drag and drop the file) /sdcard/

Comment: else connect the device in usb connected mode and add it in the memory. Pull down the screen from top, you will get options to select the usb connected mode. Then go to my computer look for removable disk and add the required file to the same.

Comment: install adb tools for windows. in cmd.exe go to the adb tools for windows folder and run adb push. Once adb is installed, you can use it for various debugging puposes too.

Comment: else take out the sdcard and put the video file . this is as simple as you add the music file to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't Add File From your PC you have to put that .MP4 file to Raw folder or in your asset Folder....
1st you Create Folder in Application's resource with Name = raw.

After That put file in raw folder...
And than use this Code...

```
VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.web_Video);
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.data);
```